# Webview in universal windows App

Tags: windows, excel, webview, uiwebview, win-universal-app

I am using webview control in my universal windows 10 app to open any link like: Uri uri= new ("http://www.c-sharpcorner.com"); WebView1.Navigate(uri);
Now I want to open MS Excel file in webview. I save my excel file as a .htm/.html format then now I want to open this .htm/.html page in webview but it is not open while when i try to open it in browser (Firefox/explorer)it open successfully. I copy same link and pass in  WebView1.Navigate(//link//); but not open. How can i open this .htm/.html (excel file) in webview.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you create a folder in your app setting, then you create your html file in that folder and finally you call you webview

```
string desiredfName = "test.html"; 

StorageFolder newFolder = await localFolder.CreateFolderAsync(desiredName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

StorageFile file = await newFolder.CreateFileAsync(desiredfName,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, ht);

string url = "ms-appdata:///local/news/test.html";
    mywebview.Navigate(new Uri(url));
```

Comment: Thanks Stanley1 for reply. I try as you told. I save as my MS Excel file in my app Assets folder as .htm/.html format. now string str="ms-appdata:///local/Assets/Excel.htm"; Uri^ targetUri =ref new Uri(str); WebView1->Navigate(targetUri); It not open excel file in webview control.

Comment: If i change  string str="ms-appdata:///Assets/Excel.htm"; Uri^ targetUri =ref new Uri(str); WebView1->Navigate(targetUri); then it generate Platform::InvalidArgumentException^  at memory location exception.

Comment: ms-appdata is used to access your appdata local folder not the installation local folder , you should use instead ms-appx ///assets

Comment: Hi Stanley I also try it but it not work. I am developing universal app name 
DemoApp on desktop. So it create A folder(directory) name DemoApp on desktop
 which contain DemoApp and Debug, x64,.vs, ipch directory and in  DemoApp/DemoApp
 directory it contain Asstes, Debug, Genrated Files, x64 and .xaml, .cpp, .h files. 
I try to access .htm file from  different-different location but not
 sucess to navigate.

Comment: Simply There is an excel file first i save this excel 
file in .htm/.html format on my desktop in a folder now this folder contains are a.htm
 file and a directory with same name when i open this .htm file in browser then it
 open sucessfully but when i try to open this .htm file in my app using webview using 
navigation it not open. where is the correct location to save as this excel file 
as ,htm/.html that  i can open in my DemoApp webview controls.

Comment: I also try using these 
hints https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3e759487-ea22-4ea6-8096-ff013fb099fd/how-to-load-a-local-htmlfile-into-webview?forum=winappswithcsharp       and       https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f16c998-f0f4-4c80-aee5-764f32abf379/webview-not-displaying-local-html-file?forum=winappswithcsharp    and webView1.Navigate(new Uri("ms-appx-web:///mydir/myfile.html")); not open excel file .htm in webview.

Comment: Hi Stanley when i debug my app then where i can put my .htm/.html file in my pc to navigate this in webview control.and what is exact syntax to navigate it WebView1->Navigate(.......);